# Is it legal for one country to be under military protection of another?

Tags: international-relations, united-nations, national-security

According to UN, is it legal for a country to be under military protection of other country?
Or vice versa, is it illegal to give military protection to other countries?

Why I think it could be illegal because military protections can cause WW3, as countries would be pulled into the wars of other countries.

Comment: The USA offered Japan military protection at the end of the pacific WWII. "illegal" by international law has very little meaning.

Comment: @user1873 I mean does UN support or oppose such agreements?

Comment: "Does the UN support," what portion of it? The members of the security council, the whole body, some percentage of it?

Comment: Do you mean mutual defense treaties?

Comment: There's also mutual defense pacts, like NATO, where the US and other members are obliged to treat an attack on any member like an attack on all the members, effectively making Western Europe a de facto American protectorate.  (A bit less so, nowadays).

Answer (score 8):

This arrangement is called a "[protectorate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protectorate)" and is used by small countries all around the world.

Some that come to mind immediately:

- Italy has Vatican City and San Marino
- France has Monaco and Andorra
- the USA has the Marshall Islands, Amerocan Samoa, and several other Pacfic islands- at one time even including the Phillipines
- the Uk has several former colonies that are now independent but still ask for British protection
- Russia has South Ossetia, Abkhazia, and several other disputed states. Apparently, Crimea just joined that list on Saturday, at least by its own rules.

Protectorates are recognized by international law and norms, and are thus as "legal" as anything in international law. Indeed, the fact that the UN recognizes this arrangement can be proven by the fact that East Timor (Timor-Leste) was itself a protectorate [under UN auspices from 1999 - 2002.

Comment: Thanks.But I want to know if UN supports this or not?

Comment: AFAIK the UN doesn't have a blanket opinion on the issue @AdityaPatil. And why would it? It really isn't the UN's job to decide how countries will protect themselves or what relationships they'll have with other countries, unless there's a clear violation of international law.

Comment: @AdityaPatil Answer updated to show that the UN supports this.

Comment: And, why the downvote?

Comment: Because annexation is absolutely NOT amicable protectorates!!! And it is very illegal! And prohibited by the Geneva Convention specifically.

Comment: The original edit was far more clear that I didn't believe Crimean annexation to be liegitimate - but it is the justification that Putin is using.

Comment: @AffableGeek Eh, that's wrong. Apparently there are no formal protectorates in the world anymore. They appear to be *illegal.* There are some quasi protectorate like relationships between states. The UN takes a great interest in ensuring diplomatic access for these states, often "commonwealths" etc... Does this really apply to Crimea?

Comment: Meh, I suppose the DV is because the answer appears to equate Abkhazia with Andorra. In order for a protectorate to be recognized by some 3rd country/party, they'd usually have to recognize the territory as sovereign first. Which [a lot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_relations_of_Andorra) of countries do for Andorra, but [much fewer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_relations_of_Abkhazia#Diplomatic_relations) for Abkhazia. Also Abkhazia [claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abkhazian_Armed_Forces) to have its own army, so it's not pretending to be a protectorate, *de jure*.

Comment: That they'd stand to lose in a war with Georgia without being backed by an alliance with Russia is a different matter. Many small countries would lose a war with a big[ger] neighbor sans some alliance(s).

Comment: The U.S. does have active protection of nations, but most of these are nations where the U.S. has active military bases (Germany, Italy, and Japan are some.  In the case of Japan, because their constitution forbids an offensive military, the U.S. Military is the de facto offensive military of Japan.  South Korea would be another such nation.).  The U.S. Pacific holdings are U.S. territorial possessions, and the Philippines were a U.S. colony/territorial possession until it's independence that was seized following the Spanish American War.

Answer (score 6):

One interpretation of your question is "are countries allowed to form military alliances, bound by treaties, in which each country promises to come the military aid of the other?"

These treaties are completely normal in international law.  The best known is the NATO treaty, but there are others, such as the US-South Korea Mutual Defense Treaty.

South Korea does not become a protectorate but does get security guarantees. In return, the US can station troops in US bases on Korean soil.

As international law is based on the rules and traditions that have built up between nations, the complete normality of such arrangements indicates that they are in no way illegal.  The UN is defined by will of its members, particularly the five permanent security council members.  The US is one of these.

Answer (score 5):

The UN charter [says](https://www.un.org/en/about-us/un-charter/chapter-7):

> **Article 51**
>
> Nothing in the present Charter shall impair the inherent right of individual or collective self-defence if an armed attack occurs against a Member of the United Nations, until the Security Council has taken measures necessary to maintain international peace and security.

So yes, mutual defense treaties are explicitly allowed by the UN charter.